# 'ActiveXObject' is not defined no-undef [React-Js]

Tags: javascript, reactjs, activexobject

I am trying to parse XML Response un ReactJs.

```
var parser, xmlDoc;
var text = "<bookstore><book>" +
"<title>Everyday Italian</title>" +
"<author>Giada De Laurentiis</author>" +
"<year>2005</year>" +
"</book></bookstore>";

if (window.DOMParser) {
    // code for modern browsers
    parser = new DOMParser();
    xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(text,"text/xml");
  } else {
    // code for old IE browsers
  xmlDoc = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
    xmlDoc.async = false;
    xmlDoc.loadXML(text);
  }
```

Above code works fine in React if i remove *else*  part , but project requirement is to support >=IE7 browsers using ReactJs. Also above code is working good if i embed JS into simple HTML page. Please let me know if i am missing something.

Comment: So define it as a global on the page.

Comment: Not the complete answer you're looking for since I'm not familiar with old browser support but you should make your *else* an *else if* and also check for the existence of ActiveXObject (like you did with DOMParser) before using it.  This will at least get rid of your error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So use `window.ActiveXObject` instead of just `ActiveXObject` to get around the global. I assume your linter is set up to allow `window`.

or set up your linter to allow it

```
"eslintConfig": {
  "globals": {
    "window": true,
    "ActiveXObject": true
  }
}
```

or set it on the page

```
/* global ActiveXObject */
```